Environment variable set as password is appearing as empty string in Python Environ library
I just noticed that when I set an environment variable as PASSWORD for my script in Python, I am using the python-environ library to read and access environment variables, the value for the environment variable set to password appears as an empty string, setting the environment variable to another other thing but the word PASSWORD works, I do not understand why this is the case, and I can not seem to find a documented explanation or justification for this.
.env
USERNAME=testuser
PASSWORD=sdfnsidufbsdufbsiudf
PASSWORDU=sdfnsidufbsdufbsiudf

myscript.py
import environ

env = environ.Env()

# reading .env file
environ.Env.read_env('.env')

USERNAME = env.str("USERNAME")
PASSWORD = env.str("PASSWORD")
PASSWORDU = env.str("PASSWORDU")

print(f"Usermame {USERNAME}") # testuser
print(f"Password {PASSWORD}") # 
print(f"Passwordu {PASSWORDU}") # sdfnsidufbsdufbsiudf


Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Have you inspected the code in the environ module?

I will suggest you use python-dotenv instead to access your environment variables and not stress yourself, you can follow the steps below.
step 1
run pip install python-dotenv, then
make sure .env and myscript.py resides in the same folder/directory
it's highly recommended you create virtual environment(python -m venv envname) in their parent folder
step 2:
import load_dotenv right inside myscript.py and os module
step 3:
call the function load_dotenv
step 4:
complete code(myscript.py) should look like this
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

USERNAME = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
PASSWORD= os.environ.get('PASSWORD')
PASSWORDU = os.environ.get('PASSWORDU')


print(f"Usermame {USERNAME}") # testuser
print(f"Password {PASSWORD}") # 
print(f"Passwordu {PASSWORDU}") # sdfnsidufbsdufbsiudf


Should be  like this brace bracket:
SERNAME = env.str["USERNAME"]
PASSWORD = env.str["PASSWORD"]
PASSWORDU = env.str["PASSWORDU"]


  File "/Users/Apple/Desktop/test_bot/config.py", line 10, in <module>
    PASSWORDU = env.str["PASSWORDU"]
                ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable```

Use this os.getlogin() in line 4
